# R: Analyse trends in mixed-effects model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have a variable `yi` that represents a treatment effect over time `nyears` for a bunch of different studies (`Site`). There are also two grouping factors with two levels each: `N`(Nhigh/Nlow) and `Myc`(AM/ECM). I need to know if `yi`shows a significant positive or negative trend over time `nyears`, and if the trends changes among subgroups `N`x`Myc`.

The mixed-effects models shows a significant triple interaction `nyears` * `N`*`Myc`

```
library(lme4)
library(car)    
> mod <- lmer(yi ~ N*Myc*nyears + (1|Site), data = df)
> Anova(mod)
    Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

    Response: yi
                   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
    N             0.7468  1   0.387489   
    Myc           0.0875  1   0.767403   
    nyears        1.1217  1   0.289559   
    N:Myc         0.5428  1   0.461272   
    N:nyears      2.2371  1   0.134733   
    Myc:nyears    0.6318  1   0.426691   
    N:Myc:nyears 10.8108  1   0.001009 **
```

How can I now find out the sign of the slope and significance for each of the 4 subgroups?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value of the slope (on `nyears`, right?) is given by

```
nyears
nyears + N:nyears
nyears + Myc:nyears
nyears + Myc:nyears + N:Myc:nyears
```

for the four respective groups. (Are `N` and `Myc` numeric 0/1? They don't look like factors, judging by the output. If they aren't 0/1 the recode.)

For significance testing of the slopes, either use `linearHypothesis` in the `CAR` package; or you could use e.g. `waldtest` in package `lmtest`; or rewrite your model so that `nyears` is the coefficient of interest for each of the four groups. (For example, set `Myc` equal to 1 minus its old value, if it was a 0/1 dummie.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `N` and `Myc` are factors of two levels each (Nlow/Nhigh and AM/ECM). I will analyse your suggestions in detail and see what I can find. Thanks

Comment: Could you please specify the formulation to use `LinearHypothesis` to test the trends in the subgroups? I am confused. Thanks

Comment: Something like `LinearHypothesis(model, "nyears + N:nyears = 0")`, no?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `nlme` package to code the mixed effects model and then check the output using `summary`. This will report slopes, signs and p values.

```
require(nlme)
m1<- lme(yi ~ N*Myc*nyears, random= ~1|Site, data=df)
summary(m1)
```

Comment: Thanks colin, that works for the first bit, but how can I run some short of post-hoc test to find out in which of the 4 subgroups `nyears` is significantly different from 0 and the sign of the slope in the subgroup?